# Java String args asterisk

Tags: java, input

How can Java take an * from String args and print it out. I tried handling it with the commented portion of this code but it did not work.

Input: 1430 - 110 * 2A + 10

Outputs: 1430-110.classpath.project.settingsbinsrc2A+10

```
import java.io.*;

public class Main {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i=0; i<args.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(args[i]);

        /*

        if(args[i].equals(".classpath.project.settingsbinsrc")) {
            args[i] = "*";
        }

        */

    }

}

}
```

Comment: Yeah, before Java even gets invoked, the `*` is replaced with a list of the files in the current directory.  This is standard Windows/Unix/Linux behavior.  On Windows there is an alternate way to fetch the parms that bypasses substitution, but I've never heard of a way to access that alternative way from Java.

Comment: If so, what is the alternative way of fetching stdin with asterisks instead of using String[] args? Should I use scanner?

Comment: It's been years (probably decades) since I accessed the alternate interface, and, like I said, I don't know how to reach it in Java.  It would not be a standard thing -- someone's special native method library.  Probably best to require your user to enter the expression as a separate line, through stdin.

Comment: I'm quite interested in whatever anyone knows about an alternative way to get around the windows jvm internal globbing.

Answer (score 2):

Your shell expands the asterisk (*) to the list of files in your current directory. You should embrace your arguments by quotation marks to avoid that:

Input: "1430 - 110 * 2A + 10"

Comment: OK. Say that the end user is not familiar with coding. As the programmer, how should I take the arguments and handle the asterisk?

Comment: The behavior I mentioned is out of control of your Java program. In that case, the best option would probably to start the program without any arguments and ask for user input inside your program.

Comment: Is that an option for you?

Comment: The input is stated as "stdin" on which I am very wary about. Usually I have handled so called "stdin" through String[] args, instead of scanners, which I know can handle this. As much as possible, I want to know if I can handle this with String[] args.

Answer (score 0):

I think You are looking for something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    String str = "";
    for(int i=0; i<args.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(args[i]);
        str=str.concat(args[i]);
    }
    str = str.replaceAll(".classpath.project.settingsbuildejbModule", "*");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(str);

}
```